# Element noindex not allowed as child of element div in this context

Tags: html

```
<div class="webmoney">
<noindex>
<!-- begin WebMoney Transfer : attestation label --> 
<a href="https://passport.webmoney.ru/asp/certview.asp?wmid=" alt="" target="_blank"><img src="img/icons/88x31_wm_v_blue_on_white_ru.png" alt="webmoney" title="Здесь находится аттестат нашего WM идентификатора " /><br />Проверить аттестат</a>
<!-- end WebMoney Transfer : attestation label -->
</noindex>
</div>
```

Валидатор арет на такую запись, в чем проблема?

**Добавлено:**

> Line 839, Column 22: Stray start tag div. <div class="webmoney"> ✉ Line 840, Column 9: Element noindex not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) <noindex> Content model for element div: Flow content.

Comment: Валидатор просто кричит "АААА!!"?

Comment: тега noindex валидатор не знает.

Comment: Обычно валидатор орёт и описание проблемы тоже... 

Поделитесь?

Comment: И было бы не плохо указать DOCTYPE вашего документа.

Comment: Line 839, Column 22: Stray start tag div.
<div class="webmoney">
✉
 Line 840, Column 9: Element noindex not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
<noindex>
Content model for element div:
Flow content.

Comment: тип стандартный html5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Element noindex not allowed as child of element div in this context.
```

Запрещено использовать <noindex> внутри <div> -а в данном случае

Comment: Как решить? Внутри тоже нельзя.

Comment: Из вики
> Поскольку тег noindex не входит в официальную спецификацию языка HTML, то большинство HTML-валидаторов считает его ошибкой. Потому для того, чтобы сделать код с noindex валидным, рекомендуется использовать следующую конструкцию:

>'<!--noindex-->Текст или код, который нужно исключить из индексации<!--/noindex-->'

Answer (score 5):

noindex - неофициальный тег, используемый только Яндексом. Большинство валидаторов считают  этот тег ошибкой.

Чтобы сделать код валидным рекомендуется прятать noindex в комментарии:

```
 <!--noindex--> ... <!--/noindex-->
```